# javascript emailJS with reCAPTCHA integration returns "CAPTCHA data missing"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recaptcha

I am trying to integrate emailjs with a reCAPTCHA widget in my website.
Despite following the instructions I still get a "CAPTCHA data missing" error returned from the request.

- Sending a test email from the emailjs console returns O.K
- My domain is registered on the reCAPTCHA console
- My private key is set on the emailjs template

Had anyone ran into this problem before?